# How to increase a number but not at once (using Unity Engine)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

So say the player has 100 gold and they get another 100 gold, I don't want the display to instantly change from 100 to 200 because it's not very noticeable, instead I would want the display to go from 100 to 200 over the course of say, half a second or something, is that possible?
Sorry for the noob question but the only way I could think of was a (probably) unnecessarily complicated for loop and there has to be a more efficient way to do that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the amount is changed via script you could always "fade" your display towards the actual amount using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Coroutines (by default) are basically temporary little `Update` loops. But in my eyes they are better to control and maintain and sometimes more efficient.

```c#
public class GoldController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference the target Text component here via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Text goldDisplay;

    // How long it should take to fade the amount in the display
    // Adjust this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private float fadeDuration = 0.5f;

    // Here you store the amount you are fading on
    private float displayedGoldAmount;

    // Here the amount is actually stored
    private int actualGoldAmount;

    // This stores the current fade routine 
    private Coroutine routine;

    // Via this public property others can increase or decrease the amount
    public int CurrentGoldAmount
    {
        get => actualGoldAmount;
        set
        {
            actualGoldAmount = value;

            // evtl stop an already running fade
            if(routine != null) StopCoroutine(routine);

            // Start a new fade 
            routine = StartCoroutine (FadeRoutine());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeRoutine()
    {
        var current = displayedGoldAmount;
        var target = actualGoldAmount;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        while(timePassed < fadeDuration)
        {
            // Get a linear growing factor between 0 and 1
            // It will take fadeDuration seconds to reach 1
            var factor = timePassed / fadeDuration;

            // Optional easing towards beginning and end to make it a bit "smoother"
            factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

            // Linear interpolate between the start and target value using the factor
            displayedGoldAmount = Mathf.Lerp(current, target, factor);
            // Update the display with the displayed amount
            // using F0 displays it rounded to int
            goldDisplay.text = displayedGoldAmount.ToText("F0");

            // Increase by the time passed since last frame
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            // Tell Unity to "pause" here, render this frame and
            // continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // To be sure to end with the exact value set the target fix here
        // This also covers the case for fadeDuration <= 0f
        displayedGoldAmount = target;
        goldDisplay.text = displayedGoldAmount.ToText("F0");

        // If we achieve to reach this we don't need the reference anymore
        routine = null;
    }
}
```

The advantage against `Update` here is that if you don't change the amount, no resources are used for running the `Update` -> The Coroutine is only running when it has to.

So from another script you would simply do

```c#
theObject.GetComponent<GoldController>().CurrentGoldAmount = 100;
```

or

```c#
theObject.GetComponent<GoldController>().CurrentGoldAmount += 200;
```

You could ofcourse instead of the property use a proper setter method which first e.g. checks if there is enough gold to spend etc but that's up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to slowly increment your variable:

```
public float gold = 100;
public int goldPerSecond = 25;
public int finalGold = 100;
bool addingGold = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (addingGold)
    {
        if (gold < finalGold)
        {
            gold += goldPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else { addingGold = false; gold = Mathf.RoundToInt(gold); }
    }
}

public void addGold(int goldToAdd)
{
    finalGold += goldToAdd;
    addingGold = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With coroutine you can do that easily

```
public float waitTime= 0.1f;    
public int coinCount= 0;    

public void incrementCoin(int amount)
     {
         StartCoroutine(incCoin(amount));
     }

IEnumerator incCoin(int amount)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++)
        {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
             coinCount++
        }
    }
```

This code will add the spesific amount (in your case 100) to the real count value.

You can simply change the speed of incrementing of the value by changing the waitTime variable.